# filter array with callback function

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback

I got some problem with this function Search program names that can be limited in the number of outputs that implement callback functions. hope you can help me figure out

```js
function filteritem(str,num,callback){
  let result = name.filter( name => name.indexOf(str) !== -1 )
   result.forEach(element => element.length == num)
  callback(result);
}
function showFilter(wrd){
  console.log(wrd);
}
console.log(filteritem("a",3,showFilter))
```

My output is :

```
[
  'Abigail',  'Alexandra',
  'Amanda',   'Angela',
  'Bella',    'Carol',
  'Caroline', 'Carolyn',
  'Diana',    'Elizabeth',
  'Ella',     'Faith',
  'Olivia'
]
undefined
```

The output I want is :

```
["Abigail", "Alexandra", "Alison"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const name = [
  "Abigail",
  "Alexandra",
  "Amanda",
  "Angela",
  "Bella",
  "Carol",
  "Caroline",
  "Carolyn",
  "Diana",
  "Elizabeth",
  "Ella",
  "Faith",
  "Olivia",
];
function filteritem(str, num, callback) {
  let result = name.filter((name) => name.indexOf(str) !== -1);
  result = result.slice(0, 3);
  callback(result);
}
function showFilter(wrd) {
  console.log(wrd);
}
filteritem("a", 3, showFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to achieve with your `forEach` call? You're iterating over the results array, and actually do nothing (your function returns a boolean: true if length == 3, false if not).

What you want to do is return the first 3 elements of result:

`callback(result.slice(0, 3));`